# ZK ThemeProvider sets Include Element Style Width 100%

Tags: zk

I've recently added a simple ZK ThemeProvider that adds some CSS files, which works fine but seems to have a strange side effect... My index page looks like this...

```
<?page id="iframe" title="${labels.title}"?>
<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/dsp/web/core" prefix="c"?>
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver" ?>
<zk>
   <include src="/zk/content/outerContainer.zul" id="outerContainer" sclass="outerContainerLayout" apply="com.example.RootComposer"/>
</zk>
```

But somehow, ZK ends up putting this style into the include-div...

```
style="width:100%;height:100%;"
```

The width and height of 100% is not correct, but I have no idea where they come from. Interesting enough, it only happens to that include - not includes following. Except, when I try to wrap the thing into another include - both get 100%, but still not the includes below that in the hierarchy.

Anyone an idea where zk adds this strange style?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the [documentation](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Include.html):

> If this component is the only child of its parent, the default width
>   and height will become 100%.

Somehow this only seems to happen when ThemeProvider is used (or there was some other side effect before that prevented it). Anyway, adding a (hidden) empty div to my index page solved the problem:

```
<?page id="iframe" title="${labels.title}"?>
<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/dsp/web/core" prefix="c"?>
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver" ?>
<zk>
   <include src="/zk/content/outerContainer.zul" id="outerContainer" sclass="outerContainerLayout" apply="com.example.RootComposer"/>
   <div sclass="hidden"/> <-- Cannot have a poor, sad, alone include -->
</zk>
```

Now the style of the include-div is empty, as it should be.